# PHP date with timezone

Tags: php, date

Need date PHP code to output this;

```
2012-11-13T19:05:05.5270036-02:00
```

This has failled!

```
$endDateTime = date ( 'Y-m-j'.'T'.'H:i:s'.'.5270036-02:00', strtotime ($endDateTime));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). the date-pattern you're looking for seems to be:

```
Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP
```

Note the `T` needs to be escaped with a `\`, otherwise it will be noticed as *Timezone abbreviation*. You also don't need to hard-code the microseconds (use `u`) and the Tiezone (`P`).

In addition, if you want to use this pattern, you should use [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) instead of `date` because the later one uses casts it's parameter to an `int`, so the microseconds will always be `0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape de T character

```
DateTime = date ( 'Y-m-j'."\T".'H:i:s'.'.5270036-02:00', strtotime ($endDateTime));
```

Comment: Thanks, I also replaced the timezone with uP as oezi suggested